# Android - onTabSelected not called at first time with customView

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am using a `TabLayout` combined with a `ViewPager` and i have set a custom view for my Tabs. Everything is working as expected when tabs are selected and unselected (the custom view is changed depending on the selected/unselected tab).
The problem is at first launch, the onTabSelected method is never called.
Here is my activity :

```
setupViewPager(viewPager);    
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);     

for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(getViewAt(i));
}

tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(this);
```

This is the `setupViewPager` and other methods :

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getContext(), startDate, endDate);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}    

private View getViewAt(int i){
    final Date currentDate = CalendarUtility.addDay(startDate, i);
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_custom_tab, null);
    TextView day = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.day);
    TextView num = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.num);
    day.setText(CalendarUtility.getDayOfWeek(currentDate));
    num.setText(CalendarUtility.getDayOfMonth(currentDate));
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Tab #"+tab.getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    TextView num = (TextView)tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.num);
    num.getBackground().setColorFilter(textDarkColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
    TextView num = (TextView)tab.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.num);
    num.getBackground().setColorFilter(pinkDarkColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

Finally here is the behaviour when navigating through the tabs
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scm9P.png

The tabs on first launch, no tab is selected
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Xgd.png

Can somebody help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter class make two methods.

```
public void setOnSelectedView(TabLayout tabLayout, int position) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
    if (tab != null) {
        View selected = tab.getCustomView();
        TextView num = (TextView)selected.findViewById(R.id.num);
num.getBackground().setColorFilter(textDarkColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tab.select();
    }
}

public void setunSelectedView(TabLayout tabLayout, int position) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(position);
    if (tab != null) {
        View selected = tab.getCustomView();
        TextView num = (TextView)selected.findViewById(R.id.num);
num.getBackground().setColorFilter(pinkDarkColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        tab.select();
    }
}
```

Now in `onTabSelected` and `onTabUnselected` method call these methods.

And if you want to launch first selected tab then in `onCreate()` method call

```
setOnSelectedView(0,tabLayout);
```

**Note :** Another way is in `getViewAt()` method just check it position

```
   if(i==0){
     num.getBackground().setColorFilter(textDarkColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
   }else{
     num.getBackground().setColorFilter(pinkDarkColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
   }
```

Comment: The first solution works like a charm, and of course the second one too @Piyush

Comment: @Leonald Great !

Answer (score 5):

There is no issue in implementing custom view.

Since first tab is `selected` by default.

That is why you need to put the code in `onTabReselected` as well as `onTabSelected` both that performs desired action on selection of any tab.

`onTabReselected` is called when an already selected tab is selected.

So on first launch `onTabReselected` will do your job.

Comment: OnTabreselected works , Usually when if some api calls returns something in that state nothing is selected and if another tab is selected then it doesn't get call then On TabReselected works !  Also I want to say I love you u saved me !!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

onTabSelected is only called when there is any change in tab selection. Like you were on second tab and selected first tab. So instead of changing your view in it. You can add it in FragmentStatePagerAdapter getItem method you'll get there currently selected position.